# rosrun gscam on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ros, gscam, camera-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS electric on Ubuntu 11.10.
I have installed gscam and its rosmake was successfully.
For running gscam, as in the gscam wiki is mentioned, I did these steps:

roscd gscam
cd bin
export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace"
rosrun gscam gscam

but it says:

Gstreamer Version: GStreamer 0.10.35
Failed to PAUSE.

In the gscam wiki is mentioned that If you see a message about a "failure to PAUSE" or something similar, the most likely cause is a permission issue with the available video devices.

Anybody can help me for this problem.

Many thanks!

Parisa.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28429/rosrun-gscam-on-ubuntu-11.10/) by [Parisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/1846/parisa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nandhini](https://answers.ros.org/users/1736/nandhini/) on 2012-03-26**:
just change export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace" with export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you've already tried:

sudo chmod a+rw /dev/video2

or similar to no effect?

---

Originally posted by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) with karma: 461 on 2012-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0